# Looking for a story about a group of children in a scary amusement park

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

I  remember an animated cartoon movie (American I think), in the early 2000's about a group of children (8-12 yo), who are in an abandoned amusement park.

In the beginning, the place is cool, they have fun. But in the end, it's like a nightmare park, the children are pursued by monsters or other strange things ... And I think that one of the heroes died ... And another was made and loved this scary-place ...

This was not very well drawn, in the style of the Jumanji cartoon :

[image: Art Example]

... I watched it when I was a child, on a movie-theater ; that's all that I can remember about it.

Comment: In the *style* of the Jumanji cartoon, but not the Jumanji cartoon, I presume.

Comment: Were the kids white? black? a mix?

Comment: Long shot, but Spirited Away? Although not sure this is scifi related.

Comment: Also a long shot, monster house.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the movie !

[Carnivale](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0202287/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl)

> In this animated tale, a group of children are transported through a portal to another dimension where they are thrilled to discover a magical amusement park just for them. There, they meet Milly (Helena Bonham Carter), who claims to have been trapped at the park for years without aging. The group soon realizes that if they can't find their way back soon, they'll be trapped as well -- and turned into objects as part of the carnival. Can the kids put their minds together and escape?

[image: DVD Cover]

Thank you

Comment: I grabbed the plot summary from Google, who seemed to have grabbed it from http://www.moviefone.com/movie/carnivale/1137433/main/

Answer (score 2):

Here are some possibilities, the animation studio that developed Jumanji, [Adelaide Productions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adelaide_Productions), appears to have only done animated tv series. But after searching through early 2000 movies:

1. [Rugrats in Paris: The Movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rugrats_in_Paris:_The_Movie): Tommy Pickles' father, Stu, is summoned to EuroReptarland, a Japanese amusement park in Paris, France, to fix a malfunctioning Reptar robot.
2. [Spirited Away](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirited_Away): They unknowingly enter a magical world that Chihiro's father insists on exploring. The first area that they explore appears to be a deserted amusement park/festival ground.

Otherwise, could you give me more information?